# Are there any books/articles that apply abstract coordinate free differential geometry to basic thermodynamics?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, applied-mathematics

The mathematical structure of thermodynamics by Peter Salamon ([pdf](http://www.sci.sdsu.edu/~salamon/MathThermoStates.pdf)) would be an example, but i would like a more abstract natural formulation of application of differential geometry or even geometric algebra to for example Maxwell relations in thermodynamics that does not use coordinates.

Comment: "or even geometric algebra"?

Answer (score 8):

some pointers to the literature:

- [Thermodynamics from the differential geometry standpoint](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11232-008-0122-8) (2008)
- [Differential geometry and thermodynamics](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/280020581_Differential_geometry_and_thermodynamics) (2003)
- [Differential geometry of equilibrium thermodynamics](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.35.1863) (1987)

Answer (score 5):

There is a calculus textbook which does this:

Bamberg and Sternberg A course in mathematics for students in physics, vol. II,
Chap. 22, "Thermodynamics".

Answer (score 4):

In this context, one should probably mention "Contact Geometry: the Geometrical Method of Gibbs's Thermodynamics" by V.I. Arnold (Proc. of the Gibbs Symposium,Yale University, 1989, 163-179).